# Express: How to get http request’s raw buffer

Tags: node.js, express, http, request

My application is running an Express http server. I need to save the whole http request message (headers, body,..) in its raw format just as was sent by the client to the server. I can’t find    Where it is stored. Any one?

Comment: In my view, stackoverflow.com is a website people asking `why` with ways they tried and error messages they have, not a place people asking `where` and `how` without (at least we do not see any) efforts. You may post what you've tried and what happened. People who know would answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole thing isn't stored anywhere.  Express uses the `http` module in node.js which parses the incoming request and headers into a data structure.  The body of the request (like for a POST or a PUT) is left to you to read from the incoming readstream so you can certainly read the exact body yourself.  Just hook up a listener for the `data` event on the incoming request stream and you can read the exact bytes of the body right into a Buffer object.

You could reconstitute the http command line and all the headers if you want from the data structure, but I don't think that original data is stored exactly as it arrived.

Some of the information is in these properties as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage):

```
request.rawHeaders
request.method
request.httpVersion
request.headers
request.url
```

If you can explain exactly what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve, we'd have a better idea exactly how else to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to archive requests and  replay them for debugging and load testing.

Comment: @DavidM. - Next time, please put the real problem into your question.  In this case, you can get all the information you want from the fields above I've given you and from that you can reconstitute the same request.  The verb, path, headers and body are all there.  Did this answer your question?

Comment: Save the requests in files/db and run a tcp client that reads the requests and send them to server.

Comment: @DavidM. - Has your question been answered now?  If not, what part of your original question is still not clear?  The practice here is to drive towards getting a complete answer and when there is a complete answer, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: Thanks. Its my first question here, still new to me. Your idea suits me well. Is the code should be implemented as a middleware?

Comment: @DavidM. - If you're trying to save every incoming request, then it would be logical to implement it as middleware.